# React-Native: chat over voice

Tags: sockets, react-native, webrtc, voip, pjsip

I was wondering do you know about some *VoIP* module or example or some documentation for something like this, I've tried WebRTC but for some reason it doesn't work with latest RN, and I've tried this PJSIP module for RN but I can't find any documentation it's really unclear to me what it actually do (https://github.com/Carusto/react-native-pjsip talking about this one), and if it could be free ^^

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can try ConnectyCube React Native video chat. 
Beta version is available [here](https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-js-samples/tree/feature/rn-video/RNVideoChat) already. 
They are working on further improvements still and there should be some new commits soon, but you can already start integrating it into your project.